# NGINX proxy_pass to Cloudflare is returning error only when traffic is proxied

Tags: nginx, cloudflare, nginx-reverse-proxy

We have several customers with "vanity URLs" that CNAME their `vanity-url.com` DNS to our `real-url.com`. Recently we've directed all our vanity url holders to change their records to point to our new Cloudflare endpoints for better DDoS protection. Everything works fine for the subdomains, but many DNS providers won't let you put a CNAME at the apex/root because it breaks RFC.

To work around this I wanted to setup a simple Nginx server that uses a `proxy_pass` to pass traffic to Cloudflare but I've run into an issue. When I have an Nginx server running with the following configs it works when the CF endpoint is in "DNS only" mode, however as soon as I enable the CF proxy it returns a 403 Forbidden and then eventually a 421 Misdirected Request code.

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
  server {
    server_name vanity-url.com;

    ssl_certificate vanity-url.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key vanity-url.com.key;

    listen 443 ssl;

    location / {
      proxy_pass https://cloudflare.real-url.com;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_ssl_server_name on;
    }
  }
}
```

I have a CF "custom hostname" with the proper cert and key added already so it *should* be doing the SSL termination correctly. I think it's a problem with the CF configs but I'm not positive.

Comment: If you don't solve your problem with the provided solution, please provide log of a single request you send (both access and log)

Answer (score 0):

So `Cloudflare` in this case has no idea what the request is coming from - a client, server or proxy. You can add some additional headers in your proxy in order to make `Cloudflare` aware of the fact that you are a proxy:

```
location / {
  proxy_pass https://cloudflare.real-url.com;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_ssl_server_name on;
  proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
}
```

Another thing to note here is that your proxy server has an `SSL` certificate and accepts traffic on port `443`. Make sure that your Claoudflare SSL mode is set to `Full (strict)`.

If this doesn't work, I'd first check for `firewall` configs on all servers but most importantly on the Cloudflare server - see if it is not blocking the requests coming from your proxy.
Then I'd just sift through the logs (access and error logs which are usually found in `/var/log/`).